# How do I cache form data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a single page application in Django.

It mainly consists of multiple, small forms that are filled in and validated independent from each other. Every form looks similar to this:

[image]

With a final button press at the end though, the input of all those forms should be processed together.

How can I save/cache all data of the submitted forms to process them with a final form submit at the end?

I tried creating only one big form, but then I can't validate each field one after the other, when the user clicks the 'Next' button.

Comment: Have you considered using the session store?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: try storing it client side using localstorage and on final submit, send all data and clear it from client side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a form spread across multiple pages with multiple request/response cycles I'd probably recommend storing it either in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/) or in the database. The session is probably easier whereas the database approach is more sophisticated. You can store items in the session using `request.session['step_1'] = {}` for example.